# Redirect I/O of subprocess in Java (why doesn't ProcessBuilder.inheritIO() work?)

Tags: java, process, io

I'm launching a process in the following way.

```
try {
    final Process mvnProcess = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "mvn", "--version")
            .directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")))
            .inheritIO()
            .start();
    System.exit(mvnProcess.waitFor());
} catch (final IOException ex) {
    System.err.format(IO_EXCEPTION);
    System.exit(1);
} catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
    System.err.format(INTERRUPTED_EXCEPTION);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Since I invoke `inheritIO()` I was expecting the sub-process's output on the console, but nothing appears. What am I missing here?

**Edit:** I know that I can use `mvnProcess.getInputStream()` and read the process's output explicitly, writing it to the console (or where-ever) in a loop. I don't like this solution however, since the loop will block my thread. `inheritIO()` looked promising, but apparently I don't understand how it works. I was hoping someone here could shed some light on this.

Comment: What happens if, in the cmd.exe, you do `mvn --version > somefile.txt` ?

Comment: @ARRG I get a file called somefile.txt with maven's version information

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: @AndrewThompson 1) I read the whole article, but I'm afraid it was unhelpful. My problem is that `inheritIO()` doesn't work (in my case).  2) I don't get any exceptions, so that's beside the point. Sorry...

Comment: So did you make it? :/

Comment: @joeyrohan Unfortunately not.

Comment: Can I start a bounty on this question in that case?

Comment: @joeyrohan Of course, feel free! No need to ask :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is an option the read it from the subprocess:

Add this code after `start()` and you will have it printed to stdout:

```
    InputStream is = mvnProcess.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I know. It works (+1). However, it only works if I omit `inheritIO()`. I was hoping to find out how to make `inheritIO()` work and get rid of the while-loop, because it's blocking my thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT).
It sets the source and destination for sub process standard I/O to be the same as those of the current Java process.